# WAMP Uploading large File

Tags: php

I have 2.24MB file size to upload to database, it displays

No data was received to import. Either no file name was submitted, or the file size exceeded the maximum size permitted by your PHP configuration. See FAQ 1.16.

Iam using WAMP server 2.2 with supported versions

```
Apache 2.2.21
PHP 5.3.8
MySQL 5.5.16
```

I made the following changes too

```
C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.2.6\bin\php.ini 
post_max_size = 750M
upload_max_filesize = 750M
max_execution_time = 5000
max_input_time = 5000
memory_limit = 1000M 

C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.0.45\my.ini:

max_allowed_packet = 200M
```

Could anyone suggest me the option to upload large file.

Comment: Did you re-start apache after making the changes?

Comment: did you make the changes to the other php.ini in your php directory too?

Comment: did you try with a smaller file too?

Comment: Thank You Friends, Its working. I need to make the changes in php/php.ini too and restarted the server.

Answer (score 10):

THIS IS WHAT U HAVE TO DO!

Go to **c:\wamp\alias\phpmyadmin.conf**

NOW set **php_admin_value upload_max_filesize** to 1024M

Bye!

Answer (score 4):

Your problem is that you modified the wrong PHP.ini file. It's WAMP trickery.

WAMP uses an annoying system where the actual .ini files aren't used - they are dynamically generated on startup. To modify the `.ini` entries, you will actually need to left click on the WAMP icon, and select `php.ini` from the context menu. It will default to notepad, make your changes and hit "Save" (Hitting "Save As" will generate a notepad error). Once you save it, then restart WAMP again.

This one got me too the first time I just went to the folder and tried to edit the file.

Answer (score 1):

There's another way to do it and you do not have to touch default settings at all.

You can use the option of httpd (apache server that is run underneath wamp) called aliases for individual needs and setup your directory structure as you like. For example here is how i have set up my wordpress with alias.

Configuration files are in:

```
.../wamp64/alias/
```

There you will probably find some files already, eg.`adminer.conf` or `phpmyadmin.conf`.
So, simply create a new file and call it with `.conf` extension eg `wordpress.conf` and inside you can make your configurations, eg. for windows:

```
Alias /wordpress "c:/wamp64/www/wordpress/"

<Directory "c:/wamp64/www/wordpress/">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride all
  <IfDefine APACHE24>
    Require local
  </IfDefine>
  <IfDefine !APACHE24>
    Order Deny,Allow
      Deny from all
      Allow from localhost ::1 127.0.0.1
    </IfDefine>

    # Maximum allowed size for uploaded files PHP.
    # http://php.net/upload-max-filesize
    php_value upload_max_filesize 20M
    php_admin_value upload_max_filesize 128M

</Directory>`
```

The line with `php_value upload_max_filesize 20M` is where you can set size for php and `php_admin_value upload_max_filesize 128M` line is where you setup your preference for phpMyAdmin.

Thought I should just point out to this as an option instead of editing `php.ini` file directly as that will make a system wide change and aliasing option can be selective.

Answer (score 0):

Go to **C:\wamp64\bin\apache\apache2.4.23\bin** (don t foreget to change the apache version if you'll copy paste) and edit **upload_max_filesize** to 20M or more and **post_max_size** to 20M or more in **php.ini** file. 
Mow restart wamp server(left click on wamp hidden icon and restart server)
If you still have problems, try to edit php.ini from here too
**C:\wamp64\bin\php\php7.0.10** (change the php version if you'll copy paste)
and restart the server again.
Now it must work.

Answer (score 0):

You Should change all files that starts with php in below folders. For e.g. `php.ini`, `php.ini-development`, `php.ini-production` etc.

```
C:/wamp/bin/{Apache Folder and PHP Folder}
```

Change `upload_max_filesize` and then restart your Apache server.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using WAMP Server then THE CORRECT FILE TO EDIT is Wampmanager Icon->PHP->php.ini, if it is not opened from icon selection then you may try it manually by accessing the following path
Installed Directory (C,D,E..)wamp/bin/apache/apache2.x.y/bin/php.ini  and by opening up the php.ini file and set the file size to 1024M.