# Image comes to server as 0 bytes on upload PHP

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, image, file-upload

If an image gets above 2MB the image comes to the server with 0 bytes.

I have already changed my php.ini file to 64M instead of the 2M default. This is happening on my WAMP server and a production server.

My code is as follows:

My HTML:

```
<div class="editunitimages">
        <form id="imageform" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action='upload.php?id=<?php print $_GET['id']; ?>' >
            Upload image <input type="file" name="photoimg[]" id="photoimg" multiple />
        </form>

        <div id="dialog-confirm" title="Really Delete Image?" style="display:none;">
            <p><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-alert" style="float:left; margin:5px;">
            </span>Are you sure you want to delete this image?</p>
        </div>

        <div id='preview'>
        </div>

        <div id="unit_images">
            <?php
                $query = "SELECT id, image FROM images WHERE unit = ".$_GET['id']." ORDER BY position";
                $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
                echo '<div class="yoxview"><ul id="sortable">';
                $i = 1;
                while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
                {
                    echo '<li id="listItem_'.$row['id'].'" class="ui-state-default"><div class="overlay"><a href="unit_images/'.$row['image'].'">
                    <img class="first_img" id="thumbnails" src="unit_images/thumbnails/'.$row['image'].
                    '" alt="'.$i.'" title="image '.$i.'" /></a><img class="sec_img" height="15px" width="15px" src="images/trash.png"/></div></li>';
                    $i++;
                }
                echo '</ul></div>';
            ?>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Javascript:

```
$('#photoimg').on('change', function()  
    { 
        var id = $('.editblock').find('#id').val();

        $("#preview").html('');
        $("#preview").html('<img src="images/loader.gif" alt="Uploading...."/>');
        $("#imageform").ajaxForm({
            target: '#preview'
        }).submit();
    });
```

and my upload.php file

```
 <?php

function resize($newWidth, $targetFile, $originalFile) {
    $info = getimagesize($originalFile);
    list($width, $height) = getimagesize($originalFile);
    $mime = $info['mime'];

    switch ($mime) {
            case 'image/jpeg':
                    $image_create_func = 'imagecreatefromjpeg';
                    $image_save_func = 'imagejpeg';
                    $new_image_ext = 'jpg';
                    break;

            case 'image/png':
                    $image_create_func = 'imagecreatefrompng';
                    $image_save_func = 'imagepng';
                    $new_image_ext = 'png';
                    break;

            case 'image/gif':
                    $image_create_func = 'imagecreatefromgif';
                    $image_save_func = 'imagegif';
                    $new_image_ext = 'gif';
                    break;

            default: 
                    throw Exception('Unknown image type.');
    }

    $img = $image_create_func($targetFile);

    $src = imagecreatefromjpeg($originalFile);
    $newHeight = ($height / $width) * $newWidth;
    $tmp = imagecreatetruecolor($newWidth, $newHeight);
    imagecopyresampled($tmp, $src, 0, 0, 0, 0, $newWidth, $newHeight, $width, $height);

    if (file_exists($targetFile)) {
        unlink($targetFile);
    }
    $image_save_func($tmp, $targetFile);
}

require_once('config/db.php');
$con = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);
$i = 0;
echo $_FILES['photoimg']['size'][0]."<br/>";
foreach ($_FILES['photoimg']['name'] as $f => $name) {
    $query = "SELECT MAX(id) AS id FROM images";
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
    { $image_id = $row['id']; $image_id++; }

    $path = "unit_images/";

    $valid_formats = array("jpg", "jpeg", "png", "JPG", "JPEG", "PNG");
    if(isset($_POST) and $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST")
        {
            echo $size = $_FILES['photoimg']['size'][$f];

            if(strlen($name))
                {
                    list($txt, $ext) = explode(".", $name);
                    if(in_array($ext,$valid_formats))
                    {
                        if($size<((1024*1024)*10))
                        {
                            $actual_image_name = $_GET['id']."_".$txt.".".$ext;
                            echo $actual_image_name = $image_id.'_'.$actual_image_name;
                            echo $tmp = $_FILES['photoimg']['tmp_name'][$f];
                            if (move_uploaded_file($tmp, $path.$actual_image_name))
                            {
                                $file = $path.$actual_image_name;
                                $thumb = $path.'/thumbnails/'.$actual_image_name;
                                if (!copy($file, $thumb)) { echo 'Failed to copy.'; }
                                resize(80, $thumb, $file);

                                $query = "INSERT INTO images(unit, image) VALUES(".$_GET['id'].",'".$actual_image_name."')";
                                mysqli_query($con,$query);
                                //echo "<img src='unit_images/".$thumb."'  class='preview'>";
                            }
                            else
                                echo "\nCouldn't move file!";
                        }
                        else
                            echo "\nImage file size too large!";                    
                    }
                    else
                        echo "\nInvalid file format.."; 
                }

            else
                echo "\nPlease select image..!";

            //exit;
        }
}

mysqli_close($con);
?>
<script>
    //var id = $('.editblock').find('#id').val();
    //$('.editunitimages').load('classes/display_images.php?id='+<?php print $_GET['id']; ?>);
</script>
```

The first `echo` comes back as `0`. The error it throws is `Couldn't move file!`. This tells me something is going on from the client to the server and I have no idea how to catch it.

---

EDIT: I have discovered the following: On my home XAMPP server on Windows I can upload a 1.7MB file. On my prod server I cannot upload that file. It takes roughly 5 seconds or more on the prod server. On my XAMPP serv it takes a little less than 1 second. Now, neither can upload anything 2Meg or larger. I have a 1MB that works on both. Prod upload time is ~2 seconds. Is there some kind of timer preventing this from working?

Also, I noticed even when I edit my `php.ini` file inside of *C:\xamp\php\php.ini* I still cannot get it to change when I view the `phpinfo()`. The prod server is fine. It is set to 6M for both post size and upload size maxes.

Comment: I don't know WAMP but according to http://stackoverflow.com/a/12049114/3571802 you can't edit the WAMP php.ini files directly and have to do it through their icons

Comment: okay, so my bad for causing confusion. When I say WAMP I actually means I am using XAMPP on windows. I thought they were one in the same. Apparently not.

Comment: No probs.  Do you have a line with LimitRequestBody in your Apache config? If so try setting it to be 0 (unlimited) and restart Apache

Comment: Where would I find this?

Comment: not sure, try searching the files in C:\xampp\apache\conf\

Comment: 0 hits. I found a lot in folders inside apache\manual

Answer (score 0):

Please add to the top of your script:-

```
error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
```

Hopefully you'll see some error message from PHP when you make the upload.

Comment: Tried that. It didn't help.

Comment: Did you restart the webserver/php-fpm?

Comment: Yes, I did restart it.

Comment: Could you enable error reporting as per my post above, and try uploading again?  There's likely to be at least a warning message from PHP if the issue is to do with the file upload limit

Comment: Okay I did that. Where would I see the warning/error? Nothing is sticking out to me.

Comment: It should be printed to the screen when upload.php gets called so will probably appear in your preview div, probably the first line of output if it is a file upload limit error

Comment: Could you run phpinfo() and check the values output for
memory_limit, upload_max_filesize, and post_max_size ?  I suppose something could be overriding your php.ini settings...

Comment: Okay, so on my WAMP server something must be overriding it because it still says 8M for `upload_max_filesize` and 2M for the post max. However, on the production server it says 64M and 64M for both. And it's still not working there. AND I actually just saw that on production it wouldn't take a 1.7MB file. could it be a timing issue? Though, it does at least go through the entire uploading phase...

Comment: How long does it take before the upload finishes, in seconds?  What sort of server is the production server, WAMP too?