# HTML Form With Enctype Breaks $_POST Data

Tags: php, html, forms

a bit of a perplexing problem right now. I'm trying to set up a form to upload a video.

Here's the form:

```
        <form role="form" action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input type="hidden" name="upload" value="1">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-6">
                    <span class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block btn-file">
                        Browse... <input type="file" name="file">
                    </span>
                </div><!-- col-xs-6 -->

                <div class="col-xs-6">    
                    <h4 class="feedback-field text-centered">No file selected.</h4>
                </div><!-- col-xs-6 -->
            </div><!-- row -->

            <div class="row">
                <h4 class="error-field text-centered"></h4>
            </div><!-- row -->

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-4"></div>

                <div class="col-xs-4">
                    <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block upload-btn disabled" value="Upload">
                </div>

                <div class="col-xs-4"></div>
            </div>
        </form>
```

And here's the relevant PHP on upload.php:

```
    if(isset($_POST['upload'])){

        // do things with the file here

    } else {

        echo "No file found.";
    }
```

Unfortunately, it seems like this form is not passing any files to the next page.

As you can see, the form has an 'enctype' value, which is necessary when uploading video. However, when the form HAS that value, it breaks, and the page 'upload.php' won't receive any of the $_POST data (ie, it will show the 'No file found.' message. WITHOUT enctype, of course, $_FILES is empty.

Here's the thing: I've tried changing this:

```
if(isset($_POST['upload'])){
```

To this:

```
if(isset($_FILES['file'])){
```

In which scenario I ALSO receive the 'No file found.' message. So it seems that regardless of whether the form has an 'enctype' property, it simply refuses to pass files to 'upload.php'.

Can anyone help me out here? I'm more or less lost. Google hasn't exactly provided me with any good answers.

EDIT: Somehow, this question was downvoted within seconds of being posted - quicker than it might have taken anyone to answer it. Someone may want to look into these clearly fraudulent downvotes.

Comment: You are not checking the `$_FILES['file']['error']` array for errors before attempting to process the file upload. You will probably find that PHP parameters `upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size` are limiting the allowed upload file size, and generating a `error code = 1` in the error array.

Comment: is `upload.php` the same page with this form?

Comment: Read the manual http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php

Comment: I will check that right now RiggsFolly, but bear in mind I also checked if just the top-level '$_FILES['file'] even existed, and it didn't.

Ghost, no, upload.php is a new page.

Comment: $_FILES['file']['error'] isn't set. Fred: I don't see how that helps, since the file doesn't even make it to the second page.

Comment: I've also checked my php.ini file. The video I'm trying to upload is under 64MB, which is the limit.

Comment: Just do a `var_dump($_FILES);` on top of the receiving script, and show us the output.

Comment: var_dump returned: array (size=0) empty

Comment: And `var_dump($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']);` gives you what?

Comment: string 'POST' (length=4)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To anyone who suffers the same problem, check out this page:

[WAMP Uploading large File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12049004/wamp-uploading-large-file)

The question gives the values you need to change in your php.ini file to allow larger file uploads (that's what was breaking the form).

Answer (score 0):

Check your php.ini settings for:

> file_uploads   On  On
>
> max_file_uploads   20  20
>
> post_max_size  8M  8M
>
> upload_max_filesize    2M  2M
>
> max_execution_time 18000   300
>
> max_file_uploads   20  20
>
> max_input_time 300 300
>
> memory_limit   256M    1024M

Comment: This should really be a comment.

Comment: file_uploads is on, max_file_uploads is 20, post_max_size is 3m (I'm changing it to 8 and trying again), upload_max_filesize is 64m, max_execution_time is 120 (might that be the problem?), max_file_uploads is still 20, max_input_time has three values, -1, 60, and 60, memory_limit is 128m.

Comment: Disagreed as the most common cause of file uploads are: post_max_size 8M 8M

upload_max_filesize 2M 2M

Comment: Tried after changing post_max_size to 8m, same problem.

Comment: Try to upload a small file to test the script.

Comment: Okay, I uploaded a tiny .txt file and it worked! Still not sure what the problem is though, as far as I'm aware my php.ini settings are plenty to allow small video uploads.

Comment: can you do phpinfo() and check the values on your upload page. You may have a rogue .htaccess file knocking about. Also this value may cause issues: session.gc_maxlifetime

Comment: Checked the values in phpinfo(). max_execution_time is 120 120, max_input_time is 60 60, memory limit is 128m 128m. I'll look for a .htaccess file.

Comment: Double or quadruple your memory limit and see if that has a positive effect.

Comment: I looked for .htaccess files and couldn't find any. I also edited my memory limit in my php.ini file, but it didn't change the values in phpinfo();.

Comment: Have you restarted apache yet? Php settings don't take effect until you do so.

Comment: I had to restart twice actually, but no, changing the memory limit didn't affect the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Give the form a name

```
<form role="form" action="upload.php" name="MyUpload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Change the name of the submit input.

```
<input type="submit" name="VidUpload" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block upload-btn disabled" value="Upload">
```

Check if submit was submitted

```
if(isset($_POST['VidUpload'])){

  // do things with the file here
  echo "Form Submitted.";

} else {
  echo "No file found.";
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately no, still 'No file found.'.