# Dropzone.js & php file uploading

Tags: php, dropzone.js, multifile-uploader

Please help me i'm tring to create file uploading with dropzone.js and php but when i try to upload large files like 4mb or more my script doesn't work but in case with small files it's worked prefect why?? that is my code 
index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head> 
    <link href="dropzone.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <form action="upload.php" class="dropzone" id="myAwesomeDropzone">
    </form>

    <script src="dropzone.js"></script>
    <script>
        Dropzone.options.myAwesomeDropzone = {
          maxFilesize: 2500000000, // MB
        };
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

upload.php

```
<?php  

    $ds = DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
    $foldername = "./uploads";

    if (!empty($_FILES)) {
        $fileupload = basename( $_FILES['file']['name']);
        $fileType = $_FILES['file']['type'];
        $fileSize = $_FILES['file']['size'];

        $tempFile = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
        $targetPath = dirname( __FILE__ ) . $ds. $foldername . $ds;
        $targetFile =  $targetPath. $fileupload;
        move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$targetFile);
    }
?>
```

I changed my php.ini file but no success :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like a bad server config. Changing your `php.ini` might not be enough since normally there is a system wide limitation.
Depending on your server (eg.: apache) you have to lookup the corresponding settings.

Comment: I'm using wamp server((

Comment: Maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12049004/wamp-uploading-large-file

Comment: or you can use the latest feature - chuncked upload