# Video upload web page won't upload

Tags: video, upload

I am trying to put together a simple video upload page. I have seen in my review of PHP documentation, the W3schools website and an accepted answer to this question here previously. It seems that an HTML form and a PHP page is an efficient solution. My current attempt is here:

Form HTML:

```
<!-- From Stack Overflow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18217964/upload-video-files-via-php-and-save-them-in-appropriate-folder-and-have-a-databa/18219669 -->
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
<title></title>
</head>

<body>

<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<label for="file"><span>Filename:</span></label>
<input type="file" name="file" id="file" /> 
<br />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

PHP page:

```
<?php
//var_dump($_FILES);
//$allowedExts = array("jpg", "jpeg", "gif", "png", "mp3", "mp4", "wma");
$allowedExts = array("mp4");
$extension = pathinfo($_FILES['file']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

if (($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "video/mp4")
/*if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "video/mp4")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "audio/mp3")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "audio/wma")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg"))*/
&& ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 20000000)
&& in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
  {
  if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0) {
    echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br />";
    }
  else
    {
    echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br />";
    echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br />";
    echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " Kb<br />";
    echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br />";

   if (file_exists("upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
      {
      echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
      }
    else
      {
      move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
      "uploads/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
      echo "Stored in: " . "uploads/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
      }
    }
  }
else
  {
  echo "Invalid file";
  }
?>
```

I am getting PHP notices “Undefined index: file” from my testing server. The final result of the run is a failed upload and an “Invalid file” message.

A “var_dump($_FILES)” command at the head of the PHP file comes up empty. Removing the enctype attribute from the  tag does pass the file name, but does not upload the file. I got similar results from the W3 schools code.

I suspect it is not the code but a PHP configuration issue, but I do not know where to look. 
I am running PHP 5.6.25 in WampServer 3.0.6.

Where do I go from  here?

Answer (score 0):

The answer lies in Wamp php.ini settings. They are too conservative for large uploads such as, in my case, video files. I found an earlier StackOverflow question at [WAMP Uploading large File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12049004/wamp-uploading-large-file) which addresses the issue. I tried editing the c:\wamp\alias\phpmyadmin.conf file, but that did not work for me. What did work was opening the PHP.ini file in Wamp. Note the previous post instructs you not to go directly to the ini file. It must be done through Wamp. I modified the post_max_size, upload_max_file_size, max_execution_time< max_input_time and memory limit. I then restarted all services and the upload was successful. I don't know which modifications did the trick, but I'm happy it worked.